# Sorting a material data table to only Ascending order in angular

Tags: angular

I need to sort a material data table only in ascending order when clicking the icon. I don't need to sort it in descending order. How can I achieve it using Angular material data table?

Comment: Share your solution/attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default sort option and use sort function on the MatSort api to set that default option.
[table-sorting-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-custom-pipes)

```
defaultSort: MatSortable = {
    id: 'defColumnName',
    start: 'asc',
    disableClear: true
};
```

then use sort function on MatSort directive:

```
this.sort.sort(this.defaultSort);
//default sort direction
this.sort.direction = 'asc';
```